# The function prints the days of the week(week.name) which have the highest traffic(week.traffic). Can you give me an alternate logic

Tags: javascript

in the function below an array of objects is passed to the function. The object has 2 attributes: name and traffic. I am writing those days of week which have highest traffic to the console.

```js
function mostPopularDays(week) {

  var Days = [];

  if (week == null || week.length == 0) {
    return null;
  }

  var max = week[0].traffic;

  var j;
  var k[];

  for (i = 1; i < week.length; i++) {
    if (week[i].traffic > max) {
      max = week[i].traffic;
      j = i;
    } else if (week[i].traffic == max) {
      j = i;
      k.push(i);

    }

  }
  if (j != k[k.length - 1]) {
    Days.push(week[j].name)
    console.log(Days[0]);
  } else {

    for (i = 0; i < k.length; k++) {
      Days.push(week[(k[i])].name);
      cosole.log(Days[i]);
    }
    Days[k.length] = week[j].name;
    console.log(Days[k.length]);

  }
}
```

Argument passed to the function is an array of objects. I am comparing values based on objects.traffic and printing those object.names which have highest traffic.

Comment: WHAT IS YOUR QUESTION? AND WHY DID YOU WRITE THAT IN ALL CAPS?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply reduce it:

```
 const mostPopularWeekDays = week => {
   let max = 0; //a helper variable to store the current maximum
   return week.reduce((res, {name, traffic}) => {
     if(traffic > max){ //looks like our maximum gets toped
       max = traffic; //so set that new maximum
       return [name]; //and keep on going with today
     }
     if(traffic === max) res.push(name); //we dont have a new maximum but its high enough to count as a maxum so add it
     return res;
  }, []);
 }

 console.log(mostPopularWeekDays([
   {name:"Mo", traffic:10},
   {name:"Tu", traffic:15},
   {name:"We", traffic:10},
   {name:"Th", traffic:10},
   {name:"Fr", traffic:10},
   {name:"St", traffic:15},
   {name:"Su", traffic:10}
]));
```

Comment: If you think it does not work [click here ;)](http://jsbin.com/wuzufodiha/edit?console)

Comment: I wonder if there's some way to write it like `const mostPopularWeek = weeks.map( week => week.traffic ).reduce( Math.max, 0 );`

Comment: @shilly `week.filter(day => day.traffic === Math.max(...week.map(d => d.traffic)))`